# I am not getting the desired output as in this example

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="submit" name="button3" value="Button 3" />
</form>
```

with

```
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {
            myClass.function1();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {
            myClass.function2();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button3") != null) {
            myClass.function3();
        } else {
            // ???
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some-result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

I am not getting the desired output as in this example. The method runs independently through servlet, but these if else conditions are not working.

Comment: What is the desired output and what runs instead?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Desired Output: on clicking button1 , function 1 gets executed and on clicking button2, function2 gets executed.
What I am getting: nothing is happening on clicking the buttons. But if i dont put this "if else" condition and instead put just any one function call, that particular function runs on pressing either of the two buttons.

Comment: You should try to System.out the content of the getParameter() Map. to understand what is given to your Servlet; Or use debug tool

Comment: I did that. I am getting NULL as the value for parameter.

Comment: Do you that your map is null or your specific value?

Answer (score 0):

You may implement nested forms or multiple separate forms here.

Comment: I can't say it will not work because I didn't test it but [as it can be read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), it seems to have no consequence to have several submit in one form

Comment: Add the same form around each button.

Comment: I'm not sure repeating code would be the solution. I don't think the HTML is the problem as it respect the convention and only the pressed submit button is sent. The problem must come from the way he reads data on server side

Comment: I'm not the author of the thread. but I agree with you, he should definitely observe the status of his variable in the servlet. Hope he'll come back and conclude this thread